# Have multiple channels open on one project in Agora for enterprise project?

Tags: flutter, audio-streaming, agora.io

It's a bit hard to summarize my problem into a question, so bear with me. In the Agora documentation, they give usage examples that only utilizes one channel on a project that you create at the start of the documentation, or tutorial if you will (you create new projects at [console.agora.io](https://console.agora.io/)).

In my project, I need to be able to allow users to create "rooms" where they can send audio to each other, but the documentation only shows how to create 1 channel on your project, with only one temporary token provided. If I were to use the token in my program, then users would all connect to one huge global channel with every user on it, which defeats the purpose of creating rooms. I know that with the Android documentation [here](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/virtual_host_android?platform=Android#core-api-reference), you can just call `createChannel` and it will make a channel on your Agora project. I need to make more than one channel, so users can create their own and join other user's channels/rooms, so that should work, but how do I do this with Flutter? Switching the platform to Flutter on the documentation website shows an error. Is this not possible? How do I have multiple channels created on one Agora project with Flutter? Essentially the problem boils down to the question, how do I make a channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new project that you create through Agora's console gives you an APP ID which basically helps to connect your account. While in your code you have a joinChannel() function - now this can take a predefined value in case you want only one channel or you can pass a variable for that channel name and that channel name can be read as an input.

You can refer to this code over here: https://github.com/Meherdeep/agora-group-calling

Comment: Just to clarify, the joinChannel() function, when passed a unique name, will create a channel automatically?

Comment: but the channel name provided during join channel and the channel name given during token creation should be same. right?

Comment: @ZacharyHaslam You can have a look at this blog given over here: https://meherdeept.medium.com/joining-multiple-channels-using-the-agora-flutter-sdk-c205cda5af52